# Django SESSION_COOKIE_DOMAIN on localhost

Tags: django, session-cookies

When I set `SESSION_COOKIE_DOMAIN = '.mysite.com'` and then run the production site, the site creates the proper cross domain cookie and it's set to `.mysite.com`. However, if I set `SESSION_COOKIE_DOMAIN = '.localhost'` and run the local development server at `localhost:8000` the cookie that is created is the non-cross domain cookie `localhost`.

Why might this be the case?

Thanks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This has to do with how browsers and cookies work. Because you're not allowed to set cookies to something like .com, you can't set it as .localhost either.

You can check out more here: https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/10560. Looks like there's no real solution within Django for this. I do wish they would warn us though rather than just break.

I don't have a good solution though. For testing you could set your hosts file to use something like test.com instead of localhost to point to your runserver.

Answer (score 4):

for dev server, you can just use

```
SESSION_COOKIE_SECURE= False #default use just to override your prod setting
SESSION_COOKIE_DOMAIN= None  #default  use just to override your prod setting
```

or you can resolve domain name with the host's file

```
 SESSION_COOKIE_DOMAIN= '.localhost'
```

Or something like this

```
SESSION_COOKIE_SECURE= False
SESSION_COOKIE_DOMAIN=  "127.0.0.1"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't set `SESSION_COOKIE_DOMAIN = '.localhost'` because of browsers security features. (cf [Django issue 10560](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/10560))

However if you have `foo.localhost:8000` and `bar.localhost:8000` you can
switch to `foo.dev.localhost:8000` and `bar.dev.localhost:8000` and set

```
SESSION_COOKIE_DOMAIN = '.dev.localhost'
SESSION_COOKIE_NAME = "youcustomcookiename"
```